# INSERT INTO if id does not exist, ignore if it exists and insert new if any fields are different

Tags: mysql, insert-into

I have a table with people and addresses. These addresses get fed to the DB frequently and they dont tend to change, but if they do, I would like to keep the last address and add the new one, with a timestamp.

There is no primary key in this table. person_id is the key in the Persons table

- If person_id does not exist, add the data to the table
- If person_id exists and the details are all the same, ignore
- If person_id exists and any of the details are different, add the data.

I have tried lots of things among them:

```
INSERT INTO addresses (person_id,street,zip,timestamp) SELECT ("1","122
Farm", "4422",CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) FROM addresses WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT person_id,street,zip FROM addresses WHERE person_id = "1" AND 
street = "122 Farm" AND zip = "4422")
```

Thank you!

Comment: Threre is a 'replace into' syntax in mysql. Wouldn't this be useful? Is there a strong reason that you don't want to update in case details are the same?

Comment: no major reason other than i thought that avoiding updating the details would be faster than updating each time. I guess I could use replace into, and just create a unique index with all the fields except timestamp. I'll try.. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution I just found is:
1- Create a UNIQUE INDEX OF the relevant fields:

```
ALTER TABLE addresses ADD UNIQUE INDEX a_uindex (person_id,street,zip)
```

and then use:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO addresses VALUES ("1","122 Farm","4422", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```